# Android Auto - Callback when user connects mobile device

Tags: android-auto

In regards to Android auto how can i get a callback when user has plugged the device into a car ? I'd like to trigger an action to occur based on when the user actually connects to android auto, is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get USB connection broadcast. From there you will have to write your own logic to figure out Android Auto is in foreground.
(may need to introduce a slight delay in case android auto takes time to come up. Launcher seems to be part of google play service)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it in my services onCreate method (right form the example code):

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(CarHelper.ACTION_MEDIA_STATUS);
mCarConnectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String connectionEvent = intent.getStringExtra(CarHelper.MEDIA_CONNECTION_STATUS);
        mIsConnectedToCar = "media_connected".equals(connectionEvent);
        LogHelper.i(TAG, "Connection event to Android Auto: ", connectionEvent,
                " isConnectedToCar=", mIsConnectedToCar);
        if(mIsConnectedToCar ) {
            if(mService == null) {
                bindMusicService();
                if (mService != null) {
                    try {
                        initMediaMetaData();
                        toggleMediaPlaybackState(mService.isPlaying());
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(mCarConnectionReceiver, filter);
```